# ESlint --config option not working and still uses the same root file config

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, eslintrc, prettier-eslint

I have this in my package.json

```
 "scripts": {
   "lint": "eslint --quiet .",
   "lint:prcleancode": "eslint -c ./ci/.eslint-cleancode.json
```

The first `lint` command is configured with the `.eslintrc.json` file (in the project's root).
I expected that the `lint:prcleancode` command will get it's configuration from the file in `./ci/.eslint-cleancode.json`. But it still uses the `.eslintrc.json` in the root folder. Any idea why?

Comment: [this page](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface#-c---config) says "This option allows you to specify an **additional** configuration". It does mention using `--no-eslintrc` to not use those though

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if you have a `eslintre.json` in your root folder, you need to add:
`--no-eslintrc` flag.

```
 "lint:prcleancode": "eslint --no-eslintrc -c ./ci/.eslint- 
  cleancode.json .",`
```

source:

> If you are using one configuration file and want ESLint to ignore any .eslintrc.* files, make sure to use --no-eslintrc along with the --config flag.

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files